# Debian Wheezy, VirtualBox, HP DV6-7099EL problem with AltGr

Tags: debian, keyboard, virtualbox

I just bought a HP DV6-7099EL laptop (Italian keyboard).
I'm going to install Debian in a week or two, I just want to test the computer without touching the partitions (just in case I need support/assistance for hardware problems in the first period).

But Debian it's my main system and I need it for work, so I installed it in VirtualBox.

And the problem is this: before launching X11, my <kbd>AltGr</kbd> works in the right way (i.e. it allows me to enter `@` `#` `[` `]` `{` `}`), but in X (I tried XFCE, FluxBox, KDE) it stops working, it simply does nothing:

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>ò</kbd> = `ò` (instead of `@`)
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>à</kbd> = `à` (instead of `#`)

Using `xev` I found that the code of <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is 108, so I tried to modify the keymapping creating `~/.Xmodmap` but <kbd>AltGr</kbd> behaviour was even weirder:

- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>ò</kbd> = nothing
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>à</kbd> = `#` and carriage return
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>è</kbd> = nothing (instead of `[`)
- <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> = sometimes gives `]` (which is right), sometimes nothing.

BTW, under Windows the key behaves perfectly as expected.

**Edit:** Following the advice of trying and experimenting with a Debian live, I managed to have my AltGr working (even in virtualbox) with these commands:

```
clear mod1
clear mod3
clear mod5
keycode 108 = Alt_R
keysym Alt_R = ISO_Level3_Shift
add mod3 = ISO_Level3Shift
```

Perhaps the three clear are too many, but at the moment it seems working, and the output of `$ xmodmap -pm` shows that `ISO_Level3_Shift` has only the `mod3` modifier.

On the net almost everyone says that <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is recognized by Xorg as `Mode_switch`, but [here](https://superuser.com/questions/138708/xorg-how-can-i-map-altgr-to-the-capslock-key-to-toggle-3rd-level-symbols) I found out that the right name is `ISO_Level3_Shift` (or so it seems, empirically).
Now I'm too much tired, I go to bed. Thank you again jasonwryan and terdon :-)

Comment: Try running a live session from a debian CD to check if its not just some weird conflict with windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can see how X11 guessed your keyboard with:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     br
variant:    abnt2
```

You need find the correct layout and variant for your keyboard. Try some alternatives with:

```
$ setxkbmap it
$ setxkbmap it qwerty  #i don't know any italian variant
```

Now you can persist your choose editing `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, usually you can omit the `xkbVariant` option:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    Option         "XkbLayout" "br"
    Option         "XkbVariant" "abnt2"
EndSection
```